# Deep nested partial does not recognize local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

In a rails (4.2.3) app, I have a form that uses deep nested partials. I am passing two variables (the form object and a setting string) as locals down the chain of partials. Around three levels down the chain, the partial does not recognize the passed in variables.

## views/posts/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <% setting = get_setting %>
  ... 
  <%= render 'partials_folder/partial1', locals: { f: f, setting: setting } %>
  ...
<% end %>

# views/partials_folder/_partial1.html.erb
<%= render 'partials_folder/partial2', locals: { f: f, setting: setting } %>

# views/partials_folder/_partial2.html.erb
# f and setting are valid here
<%= f.inspect %> #=> <FormBuilder....>
<%= render 'partials_folder/partial3', locals: { f: f, setting: setting } %>

# views/partials_folder/_partial3.html.erb
# next line raises NameError "undefined local variable or method `f'"
<%= f.inspect %>
```

Is there, perhaps a limit to the nested depth of partials, or maybe I am hitting a limit to the stack size (as the form object gets copied down)?

Comment: Is `setting` also undefined or just `f`?

Comment: @carlosramireziii both `setting` and `f` are undefined

Comment: If you change the names for that particular partial does it then work? E.g. `render 'partials_folder/partial3', locals: { foo: f, bar: setting }` then `<%= foo.inspect %>`

Comment: Try inspecting what you have defined - in partial3 add `<%= local_assigns.inspect %>`

Comment: carlosramirezii: Changing the names does the same thing - NameError on `foo` and `bar`

Comment: @BroiSatse local_assigns has both f and setting defined. The inspect output is 167 kb in size, though (167226 lines) :-) But I did try in partial3 without f being passed in as well, got the same error for setting.

Comment: @Anand - Hmm, weird. If it is in `local_assigns` it should be defined. Could you paste your whole partial 3?

Comment: The actual partial is different and has a lot more going on, and sorry, it's proprietary, so cannot share as is. If there is anything specific to check and report, I can do that.

Comment: @Anand - It might happen that you are using `f` within a block, which is evaluated in another context. Variable should still be available in a block, so my assumption would be that ActionView is using method missing logic to fetch the value from the local_assigns, and this method missing is not available in the context of this particular block. You can try do `<% form = f %>` at the very top of the partial and use `form` instead of f.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I was using `render 'path/to/partial'` in some cases, and `render partial: 'path_to_partial'` in some. Changing all to call `render partial: 'path/to/partial', locals: {...}`, as suggested in @bigsolom's answer below fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `partial3` you can access the local variables through `local_assigns[:locals][:f]` or `local_assigns[:locals][:settings]`

Or better you can use `render partial: "partial_name", locals: {locals}` in your views so you'll have

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <% setting = get_setting %>
  ... 
  <%= render partial: 'partials_folder/partial1', locals: { f: f, setting: setting } %>
  ...
<% end %>

# views/partials_folder/_partial1.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'partials_folder/partial2', locals: { f: f, setting: setting } %>

# views/partials_folder/_partial2.html.erb

<%= render partial: 'partials_folder/partial3', locals: { f: f, setting: setting } %>

# views/partials_folder/_partial3.html.erb

<%= f.inspect %>
```